# Node JS Request + Express Pipe

Tags: node.js, express, request, pipe

I have a problem with streaming video files from a server to another.

I wrote this script

```js
var request = require("request"),
    express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.get("/cast", function(req, res) {

    var url = req.query.video;

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    });

    request({
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Referer: "http://example.com/1706398/" + url
        }
    })
        .on('response', function(response) {

            response.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log("data chunk received: " + data.length)
            });

            response.on('end', function(data) {
                console.log('Video completed');
            });

        })
        .pipe(res);

});

app.listen(8080);
```

But video response sometimes works sometimes is corrupted, instead if request's data is written in a writeable buffer and saved as video file  it works with any url.
I cannot found any error or problem in my code, here some urls :

> Here some url that I tryed:
>   https://gist.github.com/FrancisCan/f2bb86f8ff73b45fa192

Thanks :)

Comment: I think the problem is with the hosted URL, if you try it you receive an HTML page instead the video file http://www.eyesonanime.org/DDL/ANIME/NarutoShippuden_Ep_417_SUB_ITA.mp4

Answer (score 2):

Remove the writeHead 200, when you are streaming, you should return http 206 results back (partial content), and not http200. I have the same scenario as you (streaming a video file from a blob container in the cloud to an angular application), there is no need for the http200 response.

Update: adding some code on how I do it:

```
AzureStorageHelper.prototype.streamBlob = function streamBlob(req, res, blob, params) {
    if(!params){
        params.container = container;
    }
    blob_service.getBlobProperties(params.container, blob, function (error, result, response) {
        if(!result) return res.status(404).end();
        if(error) return res.status(500).end();

        var blobLength = result.contentLength;
        var range = req.headers.range ? req.headers.range : "bytes=0-";
        var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
        var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : blobLength - 1;
        var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
        var options = {
            rangeStart: start,
            rangeEnd: end,
        }

        //this is what's interesting for your scenario. I used to set this up myself but it's is now handled by the Azure Storage NodejsSDK

        /*res.writeHead(206, {
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Range': "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + blobLength,
            'Content-Type': result.contentType,
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-MD5': result.contentMD5,
        });*/

        var options = {
            rangeStart: start,
            rangeEnd: end,
        }

//this is an API from the Azure Storage nodejsSDK I use. You might want to check the source of this method in github to see how this lib deals with the http206 responses and the piping
        blob_service.getBlobToStream(params.container, blob, res, options, function (error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).end();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Done, but the problem remains. Even if file exists and downloaded through request can be played without problems, streamed says "File is corrupted"

Comment: OK, I have updated by answer above with the code that I use. Check if that gets you forward with your problem. In essence, the client asks for a specific byte range during the streaming, and I forward that to the server as part of the request options. In the past, I handled the responses myself (the code commented out), but now this is handled by the library that I am using.

Comment: THANK YOU! I couldn't find where it's sending res code 206 so I was trying to do this al manually, but the newer azure-storage library seems to have resolved this for me.  What is also interesting is if your code is not set to stream, and just download the file, it will still play the file in chrome, firefox. However it will not allow this in iOS.